# Jenkins not building new branch on first push

Tags: github, jenkins

I am using the github plugin in Jenkins and my automatic builds are working for the most part. However, a build only occurs after the second push to a branch. When I create a new branch using git push origin branch_name:branch_name the jenkins build is not kicked off. I have to make another commit to the same branch for that to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are your settings in "Build Triggers" section of the job? Could you clarify your question? Do you want to trigger a build for each push?

Comment: I want a branch to build when it is pushed to, including when the branch is created for the first time. Right now the "Build Triggers" says "push when a change is pushed to github."

Comment: Jenkins sort of sucks and doesn't solve many issues honestly, especially the auto merge. You will find out that Jenkins will build and send out old versions of your pointed branch from time to time randomly. No answers to why it does that.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that my new branch was no different than my old branch so it wasn't viewed as a change. As in it had the same commit history with no additions.

I literally just did

```
                 git branch -b new_branch
                 git push origin new_branch:new_branch
```

The web hook log showed that jenkins recognized the new branch but said --> no changes.

Comment: You should mark this question as answered if you figure it out